# Trouble with SqLite Journal files. "file is encrypted or is not a database"

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I still have a lot of trouble handling multiple SQLite DB-files. Every DB-file has its own journal-file, which I assumed should disappear, once the writing is done. In fact they stay, so that I'm in trouble deleting the DB-file, because the journal-files seem to block the delete request (file delete).

I'm running out of ideas now and to be honest, I'm not very experienced with SqLite, so maybe there is a simple error somewhere else.

I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper. Here is my onCreate().

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    // SQL statement to create track table
    String CREATE_TRACK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE track ( "
            + "name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + "version REAL, "
            + "creatingDate TEXT )";

    // create track table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TRACK_TABLE);

    ...
}
```

Here is an example how I'm writing to DB.

```
// add single track
public void addTrack(Track track) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Track.KEY_NAME, track.getName()); // get name
    values.put(Track.KEY_VERSION, track.getVersion()); // get version
    values.put(Track.KEY_CREATINGDATE, track.getCreatingDateString()); // get
                                                                        // version

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(Track.TABLE_NAME, // table
            null,               // nullColumnHack
            values);            // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column
                                // values

    // 4. close
    db.close();
}
```

Here is an example how I'm reading from DB.

```
// Get single track
public Track getTrack(String name) {

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Track.TABLE_NAME, // a. table
            Track.COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " name = ?", // c. selections
            new String[] { name }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build track object
    Track track = new Track();
    track.setName(cursor.getString(0));
    track.setVersion(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(1)));

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();

    // 5. return track
    return track;
}
```

When I'm done recording, I still have a -journal file. Does anybody know if the journal-file has to be present or should disappear? Do I have to close the SQLiteOpenHelper in any specific manner? The journal files are ruining my list of Databases, because every record has a ghost-entry, caused by the journal-file. Besides, I receive this error, when I'm trying to load an existing DB-File:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕ Corruption reported by sqlite on database:    /data/data/etw.com.roadtracker/databases/TestTrack-journal
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕ deleting the database file: /data/data/etw.com.roadtracker/databases/TestTrack-journal
```

If you need more information, please ask for it, I'm desperate... :-(
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one, a that time I was trying to save different entities into their own databases. Once I wanted to delete an entity, I tried to delete the db file. Now I'm pretty sure it's bad practice, the better way is to store entities in a single db and manage them with CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete)-methods.

Answer (score 1):

The `-journal` can be present, especially if the database has been configured to not delete it.
(This might be set as the default on some Android devices.)

Just do not try to open files ending with `-journal` or `-wal` as databases.

Comment: For using the databases the journal-files aren't such a big problem. As you already mentioned, I can just skip the journal-files and everythink looks fine.
In order to physically delete a file, I need to delete the journal-file first. This feels wrong to me, so I'm trying to figure out why these journals exist and why they causing so much trouble.
There are a few different ways to get around this deleting-method, but since a database can grow very big, I would like to avoid deleting databases by just setting a "delete-"flag.

Comment: When there is no database connection, all files can be deleted.